# what is the meaning of pride and ego in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is there someone who can help me to understand this sentence? What do ego and pride mean? I know what do they mean separately but I don't understand them in this sentence:

> A man who has gone from tobacco farming to lavender farming knows about things like **pride and ego**.

Comment: There is nothing extraordinary about the meanings of these two words. I don't understand what your trouble is. It's just two basic English words separated by the conjunction *and*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but this reads to me like the author has strong views regarding gender roles. It sounds like he/she is suggesting that tobacco farming is a good, manly profession, whereas lavender farming is for effete task more suitable for women. As a consequence, a **man** who gives up tobacco farming to become a lavender farmer is giving up some part of his masculinity, and has therefor surrendered a part of his self-esteem. Obviously such a man would suffer damage to both his pride and his ego.

Nonsense really, the important thing to most farmers is that they get a good return on the time and money that they invest into a crop, regardless what that crop might be.

> Pride - The pleasure one feels when contemplating one's achievements. The satisfaction that you have regarding your standing in society and the workplace.
>
> Ego - Your sense of personal identity. How you see and judge yourself.